# InkCanvas to BitMap

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, save, inkcanvas

I have a problem with saving canvas to BMP file (or any other type).

I'm trying to save my InkCanvas like this:

```
int margin = (int)canvas.Margin.Left;
int width = (int)canvas.ActualWidth -margin;
int height = (int)canvas.ActualHeight -margin;
//render ink to bitmap
RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
renderBitmap.Render(canvas);
//save the ink to a memory stream
BitmapEncoder encoder;
encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
encoder.Save(myStream);
```

But i always got an image with a black borders from left and top, equal size from point (0,0) of my window to my canvas. What i do wrong?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it into a separate container (ie., into `Grid`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it looks like your margins are affecting the rendering of the image.

I presume canvas is the name of the InkCanvas, so to avoid the black borders - all you need to do is amend your WPF frames and use a canvas to set up your margins instead of using the InkCanvas:

```
<Grid Height="340" Width="445">
   <Canvas Background="Transparent" Margin="10,10,0,0">
      <InkCanvas Name="canvas" Height="320" Width="425"/>
   </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read Bitmaps cannot handle transparent backgrounds. So when the bitmap is created it leaves the pixels as black. Just change your ink canvas to have a white background (or whatever color you want). Check this out: [WPF - Black Background surrounding saved canvas as jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622893/wpf-black-background-surrounding-saved-canvas-as-jpeg)
also you may want to try to get rid of the minus margins and just use the whole ink canvas when creating the image.

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)inkCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)inkCanvas.ActualHeight, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
```